# Domain based on alias

Tags: 7, domain-access

Currently we use the [Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) module to make a couple of domains.
Our current domains are for example:

```
www.domainemployer.com
www.domainclient.com
```

But our client now wants it to be like this:

```
www.domain.com/employer (<--- previously domainemployer)
www.domain.com/client (<--- previously domainclient)
```

I don't see if this is possible with the domain access module. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Should we do this with rewrite rules (but is this going to clash with the current existing rules)?

Comment: You are right, Domain Access is for domains. [Path Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/path_access) might be what you are looking for. Honestly - I never tried it. Play with it if you want, and post self-answer if it *is* the answer.

Comment: Have you seen [Subfolders Domain](https://www.drupal.org/project/subfolders_domain)? Isn't that what you need?

Comment: Should it be a completely different sites under these subfolders? Otherwise why don't just use built-in Path module to create aliases?

Comment: No, because with the domain module you can restrict certain content from your domains. 90% of the content is shared.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Domain Path](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_path) module can solve your issues.

> The Domain Path module allows the creation of separate path aliases
>   per domain for nodes created using the [Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) module.

Comment: I'll try tomorrow.